# Marcar e desmarcar itens CheckBox

Tags: jquery

Tenho o seguinte form:

```
<div class="dia" id="dia" data-id="1"><input id="1" name="diasemana[]" type="checkbox" class="dias_semana" value="1"><label for="1"> Segunda</label></div>
<div class="dia" id="dia" data-id="2"><input id="2" name="diasemana[]" type="checkbox" class="dias_semana" value="2"><label for="2"> Terça</label></div>
<div class="dia" id="dia" data-id="3"><input id="3" name="diasemana[]" type="checkbox" class="dias_semana" value="3"><label for="3"> Quarta</label></div>
<div class="dia" id="dia" data-id="4"><input id="4" name="diasemana[]" type="checkbox" class="dias_semana" value="4"><label for="4"> Quinta</label></div>
<div class="dia" id="dia" data-id="5"><input id="5" name="diasemana[]" type="checkbox" class="dias_semana" value="5"><label for="5"> Sexta</label></div>
<div class="dia" id="dia" data-id="6"><input id="6" name="diasemana[]" type="checkbox" class="dias_semana" value="6"><label for="6"> Sábado</label></div>
<div class="dia" id="dia" data-id="0"><input id="0" name="diasemana[]" type="checkbox" class="dias_semana" value="0"><label for="0"> Domingo</label></div>
```

Com o seguinte jQuery

```
$(".dia").click(function(){
    var id = $(this).data('id');
    $(this).addClass("selecionado");                    
});
```

Class:

```
.selecionado {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Quando eu clico ele adiciona a class, pra selecionar a div, mas quando eu clicou para desabilitar o checkbox, não volta a cor anterior. Como fazer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('div input[type=checkbox]').click(function() {
     if(!$(this).closest('div').hasClass('selecionado')){
         $(this).closest('div').addClass('selecionado');
     }else
         $(this).prop('checked', false).closest('div').removeClass('selecionado');
});

});
```

```css
.selecionado {
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dia" id="dia" data-id="1"><input id="1" name="diasemana[]" type="checkbox" class="dias_semana" value="1"><label for="1"> Segunda</label></div>
<div class="dia" id="dia" data-id="2"><input id="2" name="diasemana[]" type="checkbox" class="dias_semana" value="2"><label for="2"> Terça</label></div>
<div class="dia" id="dia" data-id="3"><input id="3" name="diasemana[]" type="checkbox" class="dias_semana" value="3"><label for="3"> Quarta</label></div>
<div class="dia" id="dia" data-id="4"><input id="4" name="diasemana[]" type="checkbox" class="dias_semana" value="4"><label for="4"> Quinta</label></div>
<div class="dia" id="dia" data-id="5"><input id="5" name="diasemana[]" type="checkbox" class="dias_semana" value="5"><label for="5"> Sexta</label></div>
<div class="dia" id="dia" data-id="6"><input id="6" name="diasemana[]" type="checkbox" class="dias_semana" value="6"><label for="6"> Sábado</label></div>
<div class="dia" id="dia" data-id="0"><input id="0" name="diasemana[]" type="checkbox" class="dias_semana" value="0"><label for="0"> Domingo</label></div>
```

> `hasClass()` verifica se o elemento selecionado possui uma determinada classe CSS. Retorna true ou false.
>
> `addClass()` este método serve para adicionar uma ou várias classes ao elemento selecionado. obs: não substitui a classe já existente, somente adiciona.
>
> `removeClass()` utilizada para remover uma classe CSS de algum(s) elemento(s).
>
> `prop()` habilita ou desabilita um elemento da página.

Comment: Quase isso, mas dessa forma ele mantém apenas um selecionado... E preciso manter todos que foram selecionados.

Comment: Sim, mas você notou que os demais não ficaram vermelhos?

Comment: @AndréBaill acho que é isso. resposta editada

Answer (score 4):

Olhando para a [especificação de ids na W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-id-attribute) vê que os ids não só tem de ser únicos, como tem de conter pelo menos uma letra.

Você está a quebrar estas duas regras. Os seus divs tem ids repetidos:

```
<div id="dia" ...>...</div>
<div id="dia" ...>...
```

Assim como os ids dos inputs não tem letras e apenas números:

```
<input id="1" ...>
<input id="2" ...>
```

Corrigindo essas duas coisas já funciona:

```js
$(".dia").click(function() {
  var id = $(this).data('id');
  $(".dia[data-id="+id +"]").addClass("selecionado");
});
```

```css
.selecionado {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dia" data-id="1"><input id="d1" name="diasemana[]" type="checkbox" class="dias_semana" value="1"><label for="1"> Segunda</label></div>
<div class="dia" data-id="2"><input id="d2" name="diasemana[]" type="checkbox" class="dias_semana" value="2"><label for="2"> Terça</label></div>
<div class="dia" data-id="3"><input id="d3" name="diasemana[]" type="checkbox" class="dias_semana" value="3"><label for="3"> Quarta</label></div>
<div class="dia" data-id="4"><input id="d4" name="diasemana[]" type="checkbox" class="dias_semana" value="4"><label for="4"> Quinta</label></div>
<div class="dia" data-id="5"><input id="d5" name="diasemana[]" type="checkbox" class="dias_semana" value="5"><label for="5"> Sexta</label></div>
<div class="dia" data-id="6"><input id="d6" name="diasemana[]" type="checkbox" class="dias_semana" value="6"><label for="6"> Sábado</label></div>
<div class="dia" data-id="0"><input id="d0" name="diasemana[]" type="checkbox" class="dias_semana" value="0"><label for="0"> Domingo</label></div>
```

Mas se o que pretende é marcar e desmarcar, então o método que precisa não é o `addClass` mas sim o [`toggleClass`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/):

```js
$(".dia").click(function() {
  var id = $(this).data('id');
  $(".dia[data-id="+id +"]").toggleClass("selecionado");
});
```

```css
.selecionado {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dia" data-id="1"><input id="d1" name="diasemana[]" type="checkbox" class="dias_semana" value="1"><label for="1"> Segunda</label></div>
<div class="dia" data-id="2"><input id="d2" name="diasemana[]" type="checkbox" class="dias_semana" value="2"><label for="2"> Terça</label></div>
<div class="dia" data-id="3"><input id="d3" name="diasemana[]" type="checkbox" class="dias_semana" value="3"><label for="3"> Quarta</label></div>
<div class="dia" data-id="4"><input id="d4" name="diasemana[]" type="checkbox" class="dias_semana" value="4"><label for="4"> Quinta</label></div>
<div class="dia" data-id="5"><input id="d5" name="diasemana[]" type="checkbox" class="dias_semana" value="5"><label for="5"> Sexta</label></div>
<div class="dia" data-id="6"><input id="d6" name="diasemana[]" type="checkbox" class="dias_semana" value="6"><label for="6"> Sábado</label></div>
<div class="dia" data-id="0"><input id="d0" name="diasemana[]" type="checkbox" class="dias_semana" value="0"><label for="0"> Domingo</label></div>
```

Comment: Mas a questão é desmarcar.. ai o background teria de retornar ao original..

Comment: @AndréBaill então o que pretende é o `toggleClass` e não `addClass`. Veja a minha edição

Comment: Aqui no meu não consegui adaptar. Me parece diferente.

Comment: @AndréBaill Repare que eu retirei o `id` do `<div>` assim como mudei os `ids` dos `<input>`. Confirme como tem essa parte no seu código